# Filtering on SQL query

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have the below query which gives me the result with column as Value_reported and value in there.. Values are like xyz, abc etc.. I need only those entries where category is "xyz". How do I complete this SQL query?

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.category' ) AS Value_reported
FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://azdevstoreforlogs.blob.core.windows.net/inews/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/531B20C3AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV/y=2022/m=05/d=23/h=13/m=00/PT1H.json',
               FORMAT = 'csv',
               FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
               FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b') 
        WITH (doc nvarchar(max)) AS rows
```

Comment: perhaps a `having value_reported = 'xyz'`  having executes after the select and thus makes value_reported available to you to filter; a where clause can't do that.

Comment: can you just post it as an answer..

Comment: done I'm not sure it's the "Best" approach but it is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED:

perhaps a `having value_reported = 'xyz'`

HAVING executes after the SELECT and thus makes value_reported available to you to filter; a where clause can't use the alias as the select happens after the where.

You could I suppose use `WHERE JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.category' ) ='XYZ'`  as well..

Either way the engine is unable to use an index unless you create JSON_VALUE(doc,'$.category') as a persistent computed column and use a index on that computed column.

So if performance is a concern, adding a persistent computed column with index may be one approach to address slower performance.  But all you're doing is shifting the processing time to updates/insert's instead of the selects.  However as this isn't a table in a database: i'm not sure that's an option; perhaps as a materialized view... Hopefully this is a smaller data set and the overhead isn't a problem.

Comment: Can you please help me here, how can I add a persistent computed column with index here.. I have multiple Json key-value pair to filter. The one you suggessted with WHERE JSON_VALUE(... works but whole reason I am doing in Synapse is to have a better performance. and the dataset is not small, its a log file stored in Azure Storage Account

Comment: Sorry, I had initially thought this was a database engine the json was stored in: 
 However it looks like [Materialized views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/performance-tuning-materialized-views) are available to you.  As such the JSON value can be pre-processed, parsed and indexed using it.  The disadvantage I can see is the real time components just aren't there if you need real time data. If you're unfamiliar with materialized views think of it this way: It's like a normal view, except it stores the result like a table which can now be indexed.

Comment: really all that's happening is you're pushing the load of the computation to a time frame you can accept so the data is already "pregenerated" so the load is done before users actually needed it.  This comes at a cost of the data is "stagnent" to some degree  More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725176/how-to-check-materialized-view-data-storage-and-maintenance-cost-in-azure-synaps and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview for age of data

Comment: Forgoet what I said about the disadvantage and real time component.  It looks like they've addresseed that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-materialized-view-performance-tuning. A materialized view stores data in two places, a clustered columnstore index for the initial data at the view creation time, and a delta store for the incremental data changes. All data changes from the base tables are automatically added to the delta store in a synchronous manner.

Comment: In all, Forget what I said about persistent columns as it doesn't seem to apply to your current architecture; but a materialized view may be what you're looking for; pushing the load of processing to "offline" from when its requested at a cost of additional storage and background processing.

Comment: Last bit I found while reading which may/may not apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-dedicated-sql-pool

Comment: just to give more context here, I am looking to Query log files which are generated from Azure Diagnostic and stored in storage account. the data size we are looking to query or scan is around 1 TB. and everyday there is a ingestion of around 100 GB/day.. total number of days being stored is around 400. But we dont need to query 400 days but 30-60 days max at a time. We have two option either Synapse or  Azure Databricks..and selection has to be done based on performance and cost